# ActionScript/Flex: Augment MouseEvents with extra information

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I've got a business class, `Spam` and the corresponding view class, `SpamView`.

How can I augment `MouseEvent`s coming out of `SpamView` so the `MouseEvent`s  which come out of it contain a reference to the instance of `Spam` which the `SpamView` is displaying?

Here's how I'd like to use it:

```
class ViewContainer {
    ...
        for each (spam in spams) {
            addChild(new SpamView(spam));
    ...

    function handleMouseMove(event:MouseEvent) {
        if (event is SpamViewMouseEvent)
            trace("The mouse is being moved over spam:", spam)
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Things I've considered which *don't work*:

- Adding event listeners to each `SpamView`: the book keeping (making sure that they are added/removed properly) is a pain.
- Using `event.target`: the event's target may be a child of the `SpamView` (which isn't very useful)
- Listening for a `MouseEvent`, creating a new `SpamViewMouseEvent`, copying all the fields over, then dispatching that: copying all the fields manually is also a pain.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this puppy.  I would use your #2 option, but build a utility function that gets all of the spamViews on the screen and do a couple of if-elses in looping over your spamViews.

var targ : DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.target)

If(targ is SpamView) //then you know what's up.

If( loopedSpamView.contains(targ) ) // then the target is inside the spamViewContainer and you should be cool.

Best of luck,
Jeremy